# Why the below lisp code is not giving desired result

Tags: lisp

I have a list

```
'((1 2 (A B C)) (2 3 (B C D)) (4 5 (C D F)))
```

I want to process the elements in the inner list, (in this case, I want to change `(A B C)` and other lists to `(M M M)`).

I wrote a code `(process lst)`, which will do this task for the inner list.

```
(defun process (lst)
  (cond
    ((null lst) '())
    (T (cons 'M (process (cdr last))))))
```

And when I call from the main function,

```
(defun iterate-list (lst)
  (cond
    ((null lst) '())
    ((listp (car lst)) 
     (cons (process (car lst)) 
           (iterate-list (cdr lst))))
    (T 
     (cons (car lst) 
           (iterate-list (cdr lst))))))
```

I am getting `((M M M) (M M M) (M M M))` instead of `((1 2 (M M M)) (2 3 (M M M)) (4 5 (M M M)))`.

But when I use the same function, with just `(cons (car lst)) (iterate-list (cdr  lst)))` in the second condition `(listp (car lst))`, I am getting the correct answer, that is

```
'((1 2 (A B C)) (2 3 (B C D)) (4 5 (C D F)))
```

I don't know where I am making the mistake.

Comment: You say "I am getting the correct answer" but the list is the same as the input list, is this a typo?

Comment: Sorry, it is not a typo. In the simple iteration, I was able to iterate both individual atoms and list items within the list.  I am doing two `cons` one for `listp` another for `T`. I wanted to modify the `cons` for `listp` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NB. You need to rename `last` to `lst` in `process`.

> I am getting ((M M M) (M M M) (M M M)) instead of ((1 2 (M M M)) (2 3 (M M M)) (4 5 (M M M))).

The code works, but not that at the depth you want:

```
(process '(a b c d))
=> (M M M M)

(iterate-list '(1 2 (A B C)))
=> (1 2 (M M M))
```

In order to process all lists in your root list, you could do this:

```
(mapcar #'iterate-list '((1 2 (A B C))
                         (2 3 (B C D))
                         (4 5 (C D F))))

=> ((1 2 (M M M)) (2 3 (M M M)) (4 5 (M M M)))
```

Comment: Sorry, `last` was autocorrect by Grammarly.  I corrected at many places but missed this one.

Comment: This was the exact answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you want something practical, I would suggest the `subst` function from the `Common LISP Standard Library`.

http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_substc.htm

```
(setq tree1 '(1 (1 2) (1 2 3) (1 2 3 4))) =>  (1 (1 2) (1 2 3) (1 2 3 4))
(subst "two" 2 tree1) =>  (1 (1 "two") (1 "two" 3) (1 "two" 3 4))
(subst "five" 5 tree1) =>  (1 (1 2) (1 2 3) (1 2 3 4))
```

You can also add you own equality function by using the variant `subst-if` with a lambda function.

Comment: Nice answer, maybe you could add an example for OP's case, for example by substituting all symbols in a tree by 'M?

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I was looking for this, but couldn't find on the site.  My bad.

Comment: I can use both the answer, but cannot select both as right answers.